# Cyclic Dependency in reentrant flex / bison headers with union YYSTYPE

Tags: header-files, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I have a problem where I believe there is a cyclic dependency  between the headers generated by `flex` and `bison`. The type `yyscan_t` is defined in the lex header and needed in the yacc header. The macro `YYSTYPE` is defined in the yacc header and needed in the lex header. No matter which order I import the two headers, the other will not be happy.

**reentrant.lex:**

```
%{
#include "reentrant.yacc.h"
%}

%option reentrant bison-bridge

%%

[0-9]+     { yylval->int_value = atoi(yytext); return INT_TERM; }
[a-zA-Z]+  { yylval->str_value = strdup(yytext); return STR_TERM; }
,          { return COMMA;    }
```

**reentrant.yacc:**

```
%{

// UN-COMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE TO "FIX" THE CYCLE
//typedef void * yyscan_t

#include "reentrant.yacc.h"
#include "reentrant.lex.h"

void yyerror(yyscan_t scanner, char * msg);
%}

%define api.pure full 
%lex-param {yyscan_t scanner}
%parse-param {yyscan_t scanner}

%union {
  int int_value;
  char * str_value;
}

%token <int_value> INT_TERM
%token <str_value> STR_TERM
%token COMMA
%type  <int_value> int_non_term
%type  <str_value> str_non_term

%%

complete : int_non_term str_non_term { printf(" === %d === %s === \n", $1, $2); }

int_non_term : INT_TERM COMMA { $$ = $1; }
str_non_term : STR_TERM COMMA { $$ = $1; }

%%

int main(void) {
  yyscan_t scanner;

  yylex_init(&scanner) ;
  yyset_debug(1, scanner);
  yydebug=1;

  int val = yyparse(scanner);

  yylex_destroy (scanner) ;
  return val;
}

int yywrap (yyscan_t scanner) {
  return 1;
}

void yyerror(yyscan_t scanner, char * msg) {
  fprintf(stderr, msg);
}
```

**GCC Output:**

```
In file included from reentrant.yacc:5:0:
reentrant.yacc.h:74:14: error: unknown type name ‘yyscan_t’
 int yyparse (yyscan_t scanner);
              ^~~~~~~~
```

**Command Arguments Used:**

```
bison -vt --debug --defines=reentrant.yacc.h -o reentrant.yacc.c reentrant.yacc
flex -8 -d --header-file=reentrant.lex.h -o reentrant.lex.c reentrant.lex 
gcc -Wall -Wno-unused-function -g reentrant.lex.c reentrant.yacc.c -o reentrant
```

**Software Versions:**

```
$ flex --version
flex 2.6.4

$ bison --version
bison (GNU Bison) 3.0.4
Written by Robert Corbett and Richard Stallman.

Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 6.3.1 20170306
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

**YYSTYPE:**

Here you can see that `YYSTYPE` is defined in the yacc header and consumed in the lex header.

```
$ grep 'YYSTYPE' *.h 
reentrant.lex.h:YYSTYPE * yyget_lval ( yyscan_t yyscanner );
reentrant.lex.h:void yyset_lval ( YYSTYPE * yylval_param , yyscan_t yyscanner );
reentrant.lex.h:               (YYSTYPE * yylval_param , yyscan_t yyscanner);
reentrant.lex.h:               (YYSTYPE * yylval_param , yyscan_t yyscanner)
reentrant.yacc.h:#if ! defined YYSTYPE && ! defined YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED
reentrant.yacc.h:union YYSTYPE
reentrant.yacc.h:typedef union YYSTYPE YYSTYPE;
reentrant.yacc.h:# define YYSTYPE_IS_TRIVIAL 1
reentrant.yacc.h:# define YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED 1
```

**yyscan_t:**

Here you can see that `yyscan_t` is defined in the lex header and consumed in the yacc header.

```
$ grep 'yyscan_t' *.h        
reentrant.lex.h:typedef void* yyscan_t;
<snip lots of function decls including yyscan_t>
reentrant.yacc.h:int yyparse (yyscan_t scanner);
```

Comment: Hey. I know it's been a long time, but I finally got around to writing up a more detailed answer about this issue. You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850242/thread-safe-reentrant-bison-flex/48879103#48879103. I think I should have answered here and linked from there. I still need to write up the push-parser solution :(. Nice hack in your profile, by the way.

Comment: @rici Thanks for the follow up. Upvoted for completeness, even if this seems to be an endemic problem that is unlikely to improve due to backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-answer, really, but I see that the question has not received the attention it should have so I am posting this as a depressing reminder of this serious flaw in bison's design.

It is not possible (at least in the current version of bison/flex) to cleanly include the appropriate header files. The reason is the structure of the *.h file produced by bison (which is exactly the same as what appears in place of the `%union` declaration): the `union YYSTYPE {...} YYSTYPE;` declaration is followed immediately by the declaration for `int yyparse( yyscanner_t yyscanner);` (unless you changed the prefix `yy` to something else). As there is no mechanism to insert the lexer definitions file produced by flex *between* the two declarations, no matter where the lexer definitions are included, the conflict is inevitable, whether or not the parser defines are included as well. Put the lexer *.h file before the parser one (or before the `%union` declaration) and gcc will complain about not knowing what `YYSTYPE` is. Include it after---and the compiler will not know what `yyscanner_t` means in the `yyparse` declaration.

Unless bison outputs different chunks of its `%defines` file separately, it is unclear how this can be resolved. A practical way to circumvent this problem is to include the parser defines first after defining `yyscanner_t` as `void *` (whether as a macro or a `typedef`, does not matter, both work and both are equally ugly), followed by the definitions file produced by flex.