# When using multiple buffers with Flex, how do I avoid having tokens get split between buffers

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

Let's assume I have a simple grammar of positive integers and alphabetic strings separated by commas. I want to parse this grammar using Flex and Bison, and I want to use multiple input buffers with Flex, for whatever reasons (maybe data is arriving over the network or a serial line or whatever). The problem I'm seeing is that when a string or an integer (which are both variable length tokens) are split between the end of one buffer and the start of the next, the lexer reports two tokens when there should only be one.

In the example below, the chunks are  `10,` `asdf` and `g,`. If that was all in one buffer it would yield the tokens `INT(10)` `COMMA` `STR(asdfg)` `COMMA`. But with the 'g' in a different buffer from the 'asdf', the lexer actually produces `INT(10)` `COMMA` `STR(asdf)` `STR(g)` `COMMA`. It appears the logic upon reaching the end of the buffer is (1) check if the input matches a token, (2) refill the buffer. I feel it should be the other way around: (2) refill the buffer, (1) check if the input matches a token.

I want to make sure I'm not doing something silly with the way I'm changing the buffers.

stdout/stderr:

```
read_more_input: Setting up buffer containing: 10,
--accepting rule at line 48 ("10")
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: Next token is token INT_TERM ()
Shifting token INT_TERM ()
Entering state 1
Return for a new token:
--accepting rule at line 50 (",")
Reading a token: Next token is token COMMA ()
Shifting token COMMA ()
Entering state 4
Reducing stack by rule 2 (line 67):
   $1 = token INT_TERM ()
   $2 = token COMMA ()
-> $$ = nterm int_non_term ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 3
Return for a new token:
--(end of buffer or a NUL)
--EOF (start condition 0)
read_more_input: Setting up buffer containing: asdf
--(end of buffer or a NUL)
--accepting rule at line 49 ("asdf")
Reading a token: Next token is token STR_TERM ()
Shifting token STR_TERM ()
Entering state 6
Return for a new token:
--(end of buffer or a NUL)
--EOF (start condition 0)
read_more_input: Setting up buffer containing: g,
--accepting rule at line 49 ("g")
Reading a token: Next token is token STR_TERM ()
syntax errorError: popping token STR_TERM ()
Stack now 0 3
Error: popping nterm int_non_term ()
Stack now 0
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token STR_TERM ()
Stack now 0
```

Lex file:

```
%{
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "yacc.h"
bool read_more_input(yyscan_t scanner);
%}

%option reentrant bison-bridge

%%

[0-9]+     { yylval->int_value = atoi(yytext); return INT_TERM; }
[a-zA-Z]+  { yylval->str_value = strdup(yytext); return STR_TERM; }
,          { return COMMA;    }
<<EOF>>    {
             if (!read_more_input(yyscanner)) {
                yyterminate();
             }
           }
```

Yacc file:

```
%{
// This appears to be a bug. This typedef breaks a dependency cycle between the headers.
// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103798/cyclic-dependency-in-reentrant-flex-bison-headers-with-union-yystype
typedef void * yyscan_t;  

#include <stdbool.h>
#include "yacc.h"
#include "lex.h"
%}

%define api.pure full
%lex-param {yyscan_t scanner}
%parse-param {yyscan_t scanner}
%define api.push-pull push

%union {
  int int_value;
  char * str_value; 
}

%token <int_value> INT_TERM
%type  <int_value> int_non_term
%token <str_value> STR_TERM
%type  <str_value> str_non_term
%token COMMA

%%

complete : int_non_term str_non_term { printf(" === %d === %s === \n", $1, $2); }

int_non_term : INT_TERM COMMA { $$ = $1; }
str_non_term : STR_TERM COMMA { $$ = $1; }

%%

char * packets[]= {"10,", "asdf", "g,"};
int current_packet = 0;

bool read_more_input(yyscan_t scanner) {
  if (current_packet >= 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "read_more_input: No more input\n");
    return false;
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "read_more_input: Setting up buffer containing: %s\n", packets[current_packet]);
  size_t buffer_size = strlen(packets[current_packet]) + 2;
  char * buffer = (char *) calloc(buffer_size, sizeof(char));
  memcpy(buffer, packets[current_packet], buffer_size - 2);

  yy_scan_buffer(buffer, buffer_size, scanner);
  current_packet++;
  return true; 
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  yyscan_t scanner;
  yylex_init(&scanner) ;

  read_more_input(scanner);

  yyset_debug(1, scanner); 
  yydebug = 1;

  int status;
  yypstate *ps = yypstate_new ();

  YYSTYPE pushed_value;

  do {
    status = yypush_parse(ps, yylex(&pushed_value, scanner), &pushed_value, scanner);
  } while(status == YYPUSH_MORE);

  yypstate_delete (ps);
  yylex_destroy (scanner) ;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not the expected use case for multiple buffers. Multiple input buffers are generally used to handle things like `#include` or even macro expansion, where the included text definitely should respect token boundaries. (Consider an #included file which has an unterminated comment...)

If you want to paste together inputs from different sources in a way which allows tokens to flow across buffer boundaries, redefine the `YY_INPUT` macro to meet your needs.

`YY_INPUT` is the macro hook for customising input; it is given a buffer and a maximum length and it must copy the specified number of bytes (or fewer) into the buffer, and also indicate hoe many bytes were provided (0 bytes is taken as meaning end of input, at which point `yywrap` will be called.)

`YY_INPUT` is expanded inside `yylex` so it has access to the `yylex` arguments, which includes the lexer state. `yywrap` in a reentrant lexer is called with the scanner state as an argument. So you can use the two mechanisms together, if you want to.

Unfortunately, this does not allow "zero-copy" buffer switching. But flex is not optimised for in-memory input buffers in general: you can provide flex with a buffer using `yyscan_buffer` but the buffer must be terminated with two NUL bytes, and it will be modified during the scan, so the feature is rarely useful.

Here's a trivial example, which lets you set `yylex` up with a NULL-terminated argv-like array of strings, and proceeds to lex them all as a single input. (If you choose to use argv+1 to initialize this array, you'll notice that it runs tokens together from consecutive arguments.)

```
%{
#include <string.h>
#include <parser.tab.h>
#define YY_EXTRA_TYPE char**
/* FIXME:
 * This assumes that none of the string segments are empty
 * strings (or for the feature-not-a-bug interpretation, 
 * it allows the list to be terminated by NULL or an empty string).
 */
#define YY_INPUT(buf,result,max_size) { \
  char* segment = *yyextra; \
  if (segment == NULL) result = 0; \
  else { \
    size_t avail = strnlen(segment, max_size); \
    memcpy(buf, segment, avail); \
    if (segment[avail]) *yyextra += avail; \
    else ++yyextra; \
    result = avail; \
  } \
}

%}

%option reentrant bison-bridge
%option noinput nounput nodefault noyywrap

%%

[[:space:]]+              ;
[0-9]+                    { yylval->number = strtol(yytext, 0, 10); return NUMBER; }
[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]* { yylval->string = strdup(yytext); return ID; }
.                         { return *yytext; }

%%

/* This function must be exported in some header */
void yylex_strings(char** argv, yyscan_t scanner) {
  yyset_extra(argv, scanner);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the knowledgeable answer. I was a bit worried that SO was a bit of a long shot. After digging through the generated code, it does look like buffers created with `yy_scan_buffer` have an internal member `yy_fill_buffer` set to 0, whereas buffers created from files/pipes have it set to 1. So no attempt is made to refill them automatically. I will have to do as you say and refill them myself using `YY_INPUT`.

Comment: @Huckle: `yy_scan_buffer` was, I believe, an attempt to do zero-copy scanning, but as I said it's hardly ever a useful interface. `YY_INPUT`, on the other hand, is pretty easy to use although you need to jump through some hoops as in my example if you might exceed the requested buffer size (which you pretty well always might unless you are providing input one character at a time, which is not really a good idea.) I'm aware that I owe you an answer about cyclical dependencies, and I think I found some useful example code. Maybe Tuesday. :)

Comment: You owe me nothing good sir, you've already answered one of my questions. In your example, the buffer that is initially passed to `YY_INPUT`, is that the lexer's buffer? Are you still reading stdin or have you used `yy_scan_*` or `yy_create_*`? Because it looks like `YY_INPUT` is only invoked if `yy_fill_buffer` is 1, which is only when reading a file or a pipe. Could I possibly set `yyin` to `NULL`, as I don't want to read stdin at all.

Comment: Nothing in `yy_create_buffer` or `yy_init_buffer` checks if the input `FILE *` is valid. They do pass it through `isatty(fileno(...))` but discards any errors those report.

Comment: Yyin is only used in the default definition of YY_INPUT. If you redefine the macro as I did, then yyin is irrelevant. Indeed, yylex will pass YY_INPUT a pointer into its buffer, but you don't need to worry about that

Comment: The scanner initializes itself with an unfilled but fillable buffer, so YY_INPUT will be invoked right at the beginning (unless you replace the buffer with a string buffer.) I could have repurposed `yyin` to be my `char**` instead of using yyextra, and in practice I have often done that. But the casts seem to annoy  people. Putting the reader context in the buffer structure is better design, but flex isn't flexible about that.