# Thread-safe / reentrant bison + flex

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I would really prefer a working example to any explanation. Whatever I read so far on Bison's documentation site contradicts whatever Flex says.  One says to declare `yylex` as

```
int yylex (yyscan_t yyscanner);
```

another one wants it to be:

```
int yylex(YYSTYPE *lvalp, YYLTYPE *llocp);
```

What I really need is the location information.  I'm not sure as of yet if I need `YYSTYPE` (I don't have a use for this information right now, but maybe in the future I will).

---

Unrelated to the above, and as a bonus, I'd be interesting to know why this infrastructure is so bad.  It seems like such a straight-forward thing to do, and yet it's otherwordly bad.  It never works with defaults.  Even writing a simplest textbook example of calculator requires a many days of fixing configuration errors... why?

Comment: It doesn't 'requires a many days of fixing configuration errors' for me. But then I've been using it for over 30 years. If you have a *specific* question about configuration, please ask it.

Comment: I humbly request you to accept the answer posted by @rici. I cannot imagine a more complete answer to your question. It has helped me a LOT (to put it mildly) and am sure will help others.  Accepting it as an answer inspires confidence in other visitors.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### 1. Sample code

A kind of explanation of how reentrancy is configured into bison and flex is provided in section 2 of this answer. Other annotations of the sample code are in section 3.

#### 1.1 eval.l

```
%option noinput nounput noyywrap 8bit nodefault                                 
%option yylineno
%option reentrant bison-bridge bison-locations                                  

%{
  #include <stdlib.h>                                                           
  #include <string.h>
  #include "eval.tab.h"                                                   
  
  #define YY_USER_ACTION                                             \
    yylloc->first_line = yylloc->last_line;                          \
    yylloc->first_column = yylloc->last_column;                      \
    if (yylloc->last_line == yylineno)                               \
      yylloc->last_column += yyleng;                                 \
    else {                                                           \
      yylloc->last_line = yylineno;                                  \
      yylloc->last_column = yytext + yyleng - strrchr(yytext, '\n'); \
    }
%}                                                                              
%%
[ \t]+            ;                                                  
#.*               ;                                                  

[[:digit:]]+      *yylval = strtol(yytext, NULL, 0); return NUMBER;  

.|\n              return *yytext;
```

#### 1.2 eval.y

```
%define api.pure full
%locations
%param { yyscan_t scanner }

%code top {
  #include <stdio.h>
} 
%code requires {
  typedef void* yyscan_t;
}
%code {
  int yylex(YYSTYPE* yylvalp, YYLTYPE* yyllocp, yyscan_t scanner);
  void yyerror(YYLTYPE* yyllocp, yyscan_t unused, const char* msg);
}

%token NUMBER UNOP
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/' '%'
%precedence UNOP
%%
input: %empty
     | input expr '\n'      { printf("[%d]: %d\n", @2.first_line, $2); }
     | input '\n'
     | input error '\n'     { yyerrok; }
expr : NUMBER
     | '(' expr ')'         { $$ = $2; }
     | '-' expr %prec UNOP  { $$ = -$2; }
     | expr '+' expr        { $$ = $1 + $3; }
     | expr '-' expr        { $$ = $1 - $3; }
     | expr '*' expr        { $$ = $1 * $3; }
     | expr '/' expr        { $$ = $1 / $3; }
     | expr '%' expr        { $$ = $1 % $3; }

%%

void yyerror(YYLTYPE* yyllocp, yyscan_t unused, const char* msg) {
  fprintf(stderr, "[%d:%d]: %s\n",
                  yyllocp->first_line, yyllocp->first_column, msg);
}
```

#### 1.3 eval.h

See 3.1 for an explanation of the need for this file.

```
#include "eval.tab.h"
#include "eval.lex.h"
```

#### 1.4 main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "eval.h"
#if !YYDEBUG
  static int yydebug;
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  yyscan_t scanner;          
  yylex_init(&scanner);
  
  do {
    switch (getopt(argc, argv, "sp")) {
      case -1: break;
      case 's': yyset_debug(1, scanner); continue;
      case 'p': yydebug = 1; continue;
      default: exit(1);
    }
    break;
  } while(1);

  yyparse(scanner);          
  yylex_destroy(scanner);    
  return 0;
}
```

#### 1.5 Makefile

```
all: eval

eval.lex.c: eval.l
        flex -o $@ --header-file=$(patsubst %.c,%.h,$@) --debug $<

eval.tab.c: eval.y
        bison -o $@ --defines=$(patsubst %.c,%.h,$@) --debug $<

eval: main.c eval.tab.c eval.lex.c eval.h
        $(CC) -o $@ -Wall --std=c11 -ggdb -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 $(filter %.c,$^)

clean:
        rm -f eval.tab.c eval.lex.c eval.tab.h eval.lex.h main
```

### 2. Re-entrancy issues

The most important thing to remember is that Bison/Yacc and Flex/Lex are two independent code generators. While they are frequently used together, this is not necessary; either one can be used by itself or with other tools.

**Note:** The following discussion only applies to normal "pull" parsers. Bison can generate push parsers (similar to Lemon) and that allows a useful control flow inversion, which actually simplifies several of the issues mentioned below. In particular, it completely avoids the circular dependency analysed in 3.1. I usually prefer push parsers, but they seemed out of scope for this particular question.

#### 2.1 Bison / Yacc re-entrancy

A Bison/Yacc generated parser is called once to parse an entire body of text, so it has no need to maintain mutable persistent data objects between calls. It does rely on a number of tables which guide the progress of the parser, but the fact that these immutable tables have static lifetime does not affect re-entrancy. (With Bison, at least, these tables do not have external linkage but of course they are still visible by user-written code inserted into the parser.)

The main issue, then, are the externally-visible mutable globals `yylval` and `yylloc`, used to augment the parser-lexer interface. These globals are definitely part of Bison/Yacc; Flex-generated code does not even mention them, and all use of them is explicitly performed in user actions in the Flex definition files. To make a bison parser re-entrant, it is necessary to modify the API which the parser uses to collect information from the lexer about each token, and the solution adopted by Bison is the classic one of providing additional parameters which are pointers to the data structures being "returned" to the parser. So this re-entrancy requirement changes the way the Bison-generated parser calls `yylex`; instead of invoking

```
int yylex(void);
```

the prototype becomes either:

```
int yylex(YYSTYPE* yylvalp);
```

or

```
int yylex(YYSTYPE* yylvalp, YYLTYPE* yyllocp);
```

depending on whether or not the parser requires the location information stored in `yylloc`. (Bison will automatically detect use of location information in actions, but you can also insist that a location object be provided to `yylex`.)

That means that the scanner must be modified in order to correctly communicate with a re-entrant bison parser, even if the lexer itself is not re-entrant. (See below.)

There are a small number of additional Bison/Yacc variables which are intended for use by user code, which might force source code changes if used:

- `yynerrs` counts the number of syntax errors which have been encountered; with a re-entrant parser, `yynerrs` is local to the `yyparse` and therefore can only be used in actions. (In legacy applications, it is sometimes referenced by `yyparse`'s caller; such uses need to be modified for re-entrant parsers.)
- `yychar` is the token type of the lookahead symbol, and is sometimes used in error reporting. In a re-entrant parser, it is local to `yyparse` so if it is needed by an error reporting function, it will have to be passed explicitly.
- `yydebug` controls whether a parse trace is produced, if debugging code has been enabled. `yydebug` is still global in a re-entrant parser, so it is not possible to enable debugging traces only for a single parser instance. (I regard this as a bug, but it could be considered a feature request.)

  Debugging code is enabled by defining the preprocessor macro `YYDEBUG` or by using the `-t` command-line flag. These are defined by Posix; Flex also provides the `--debug` command line flag; the `%debug` directive and the `parse.trace` configuration directive (which can set with `-Dparse.trace` on the bison command line.

#### 2.2 Flex / Lex re-entrancy

`yylex` is called repeatedly over the course of the parse; each time it is called, it returns a single token. It needs to maintain a large amount of persistent state between calls, including its current buffer and various pointers tracking lexical progress.

In a default lexer, this information is kept in a global `struct` which is not intended to be referenced by user code, except for specific global variables (which are mostly macros in modern Flex templates).

In a re-entrant lexer, all of Flex's persistent information is collected into an opaque data structure pointed to by a variable of type `yyscan_t`. This variable must be passed to every call to Flex functions, not just `yylex`. (The list includes, for example, the various buffer management functions.) The Flex convention is that the persistent state object is always the *last* argument to a function. Some globals which have been relocated into this data structure have associated macros, so that it is possible to refer to them by their traditional names Flex actions. Outside of `yylex`, all accesses (and modifications, in the case of mutable variables) must be done with getter and setter functions documented in the [Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Reentrant-Functions.html). Obviously, the list of getter/setter functions does not include accessors for *Bison* variables, such as `yylval`.

So `yylex` in a re-entrant *scanner* has the prototype

```
int yylex(yyscan_t state);
```

#### 2.3 Communication between parser and scanner

Flex/lex itself only recognizes tokens; it is up to the user action associated with each pattern to communicate the result of the match. Conventionally, parsers expect that `yylex` will return a small integer representing the token's syntactic type or 0 to indicate that the end of input has been reached. The token's text is stored in the variable (or yyscan_t member) `yytext` (and its length in `yyleng`) but since `yytext` is a pointer to an internal buffer in the generated scanner, the string value can only be used before the next call to `yylex`. Since LR parsers do not generally process semantic information until several tokens have been read, `yytext` is not an appropriate mechanism for passing semantic information.

As mentioned above, non-reentrant Bison/Yacc generated parsers provide assume the use of the global `yylval` to communicate semantic information, as well as the `yylloc` global to communicate source location information, if that is desired (Bison only).

But, as noted above, in a re-entrant parser these variables are local to `yyparse` and the parser passes *pointers* to the variables on each call to the lexer. This requires changes to the prototype of `yylex`, as well as to any scanner actions which use `yylval` and/or `yylloc`.

The prototype expected by a reentrant bison-generated parser is:

```
int yylex(YYSTYPE* yylvalp, YYLTYPE* yyllocp, yyscan_t state);
```

(If locations are not used, the `yyllocp` argument is eliminated.)

Flex's `%bison-bridge` directive (or the combination of `%bison-bridge` and `%bison-locations` if location tracking is being used) will ensure that the `yylex` prototype is correct.

All references to `yylval` in scanner actions also need to be modified, since bison's reentrant API passes pointers to the semantic value and location objects. If the semantic type is a `union` (normally produced by placing a `%union` declaration in the bison source), then you'll need to change scanner actions which use `yylval.tag` to `yylval->tag`. Similarly, if you use a single semantic type, either the default type or one declared (in the bison source) with `%define api.value.type`, then you'll need to replace `yylval = ...` with `*yylval = ...`, as in the sample code above.

### 3. Notes on the sample code

#### 3.1. Circular header dependency

Given the above, it is impossible to declare `yylex()` until `YYSTYPE` has been declared. Also it is impossible to declare `yyparse()` until `yyscan_t` has been declared. Since `yylex` and `yyscan_t` are in the flex-generated header and `yyparse` and `YYSTYPE` are in the bison-generated header, neither inclusion order for the two headers can work. Or, to put it another way, there is a circular dependency.

Since `yyscan_t` is just a type alias for `void*` (rather than being a pointer to an incomplete type, which is arguably a cleaner way of passing pointers to opaque datastructures), the cycle can be broken by inserting a redundant `typedef`:

```
typedef void* yyscan_t;
#include "flex.tab.h"
#include "flex.lex.h"
```

That works fine. The next step would appear to be to put both the `typedef` and the second `#include` inside the bison-generated header `flex.tab.h`, using a `code requires` block to put the `typedef` near the beginning and a `code provides` block to put the `#include` near the end (or at least after the `YYSTYPE` declaration). Unfortunately, that does not work, because `flex.tab.h` is included in the flex-generated scanner code. That would have the result of including the flex-generated header into the flex-generated source code, and that is not supported. (Although the flex-generated header does have a header guard, the generated source file does not require the header file to exist, so it contains a copy of the contents rather than an `#include` statement, and the copy does not include the header guard.)

In the sample code, I did the next best thing: I used a `code requires` block to insert the `typedef` into the bison-generated header, and created an additional `eval.h` header file which can be used by other translation units which includes the bison- and flex-generated headers in the correct order.

That's ugly. Other solutions have been proposed, but they are all, IMHO, equally ugly. This just happens to be the one which I use.

#### 3.2. Source locations

Both the yylex and yyerror prototypes vary depending on whether or not source locations are required by the parser. Since these changes will reverberate through the various project files, I think that the most advisable is to force the usage of location information, even if it is not (yet) being used by the parser. Someday you might want to use it, and the runtime overhead of maintaining it is not enormous (although it is measurable, so you might want to ignore this advice in resource-constrained environments).

To simplify the load, I include a simple general implementation in lines 10-17 of `flex.l` which uses on the `YY_USER_ACTION` to insert code at the beginning of all flex rule actions. This `YY_USER_ACTION` macro should work for any scanner which does not use `yyless()`, `yymore()`, `input()` or `REJECT`. Correctly coping with these features is not too difficult but it seemed out of scope here.

#### 3.3 Bison error recovery

The sample code implements a simple line-oriented calculator, which can be used for interactive evaluation. (Some other features useful for interactive evaluation were not included. An interactive calculator could benefit greatly from `readline()` integration and access to previously calculated values; variables and named constants would also be handy.) To make interactive use reasonable, I inserted a very minimal error recovery strategy: the `error` production at line 24 of `flex.y` discards tokens until a newline is encountered and then uses `yyerrok` to avoid discarding error messages.

#### 3.4 Debugging traces

Bison and Yacc generated parsers follow the Posix requirement that debugging code in the generated source is not compiled unless the preprocessor macro `YYDEBUG` is defined and has a non-zero value. If debugging code is compiled into the binary, then debugging traces are controlled by the global variable `yydebug`. If `YYDEBUG` is non-zero, `yydebug` is given a default value of 0, which disables traces. If `YYDEBUG` is 0, `yydebug` is not defined by the bison/yacc-generated code. If `YYDEBUG` is not defined, then it will be defined by the generated code, with value 0 unless the `-t` command-line option is used, in which case it will have default value 1.

Bison inserts the `YYDEBUG` macro definition into the generated header file (although it is not obliged by Posix to do so), so I test for it in `main.c` and provide an alternative definition of the `yydebug` variable if it has not been defined. This allows the code which enables debugging traces to compile even if it is not going to be able to turn on tracing.

Flex-generated code normally uses the global variable `yy_flex_debug` to turn traces on and off; unlike yacc/bison, the default value of `yy_flex_debug` is 1 if debugging code is compiled into the executable. Since a reentrant scanner cannot use global variables, the reentrant scanner puts the debug enabler into the `yyscan_t` object, where it can be accessed with the `yyset_debug` and `yyget_debug` access functions, which are defined whether or not debugging code has been compiled. However, the default value of the re-entrant debugging flag is 0, so if you create a reentrant scanner, you need to explicitly enable tracing even if tracing has been compiled into the executable. (This makes a reentrant scanner more like a parser.)

The sample `main` program turns on scanner tracing if run with the `-s` command-line option, and parser tracing with the `-sp` option.

Comment: Thank you for the very useful explanation! However, I need to parse a lot of inputs in parallel (tens of millions). I started making the yystack_ member composable (in ppl.h terms), but got issues in writing accessors for $1/$2/$3 in .yy grammar. Basically, $1 is being replaced by parser generator (bison 3.0.4) with yystack_[1].value.str, but I need the following: yystack_.local().operator[](1).value.str. Could you suggest how this could be achieved? Is it possible to parse in parallel using bison?

Comment: @Terry: I don't think your problem is sufficiently similar to the OP to make it appropriate to modify my answer to cover both issues. For one thing, you are evidently using the C++ skeleton. Perhaps you'd like to write a complete question, in which you explain your terms more fully -- I suspect I'm not the only one with only a fuzzy idea of what the Windows-specific `ppl.h` header is about -- and perhaps explaining why simply using different parser context objects for each concurrent operation is not sufficient. (Or, if it is sufficient, what problems you have implementing it.)

Comment: @rici  I got my parser/lexer to work in a single-threaded non-reentrant manner. Now when trying to use it as a re-entrant one by following the above guidelines, I am getting the error: lex.yy.c:984:5: error: unknown type name ‘YYLTYPE’
     YYLTYPE * yylloc_r;

Comment: @asinix: In that case, you didn't copy my code correctly. From the error, I suspect the problem is that you left out the `%locations` directive. You're free to ignore my advice about requesting location tracking, but in that case you must adjust quite a few prototypes (which is why I made the recommendation).

Comment: @rici I will try to restructure my code by using your code as the base and then plugging my rules and functions rather than the other way around. Will let you know.

Comment: @rici In reentrant parser how do I set/get yylval as a string? I see in the generated code that yylval is defined as yyg->yylval_r. I want, $n ($$. $1, $2, etc.), to be accessed as a string in the parser. Any union def required? Any macro/function?

Comment: @rici Got my re-entrant parser and lexer to work. Your code is very helpful.

Comment: This answer, if augmented by a case involving non-integer values assigned to terminal symbols would be a complete solution for any basic reentrant implementation. I had to dig some material to get that up since it varies from non-reentrant implementations. There are many proposed solutions on the net but this is the most complete in all other aspects. If you want to avoid digging into all the gory details of the internals of flex and bison and just want to copy-paste with basic understanding of why base flex and bison would not work in re-entrant mode, this is THE solution.

Comment: @asinix: reentrancy makes no difference in the parser (bison) actions, and you declare non-default types in the same way (a `%union` declaration or `%define api.value.type {char*}`). The only difference is in the scanner, in which `yylval` and `yylloc` are pointers instead of values. If you use `%union` (definitely my preference), you need to change `yylval.member` to `yylval->member`. You're right, I should point that out somewhere. (You can also use a preprocessor macro to define `YYLTYPE`, but you should avoid that technique.)

Comment: @asinix: OK, wrote some more.

Comment: @rici While you are on the topic, how about a few lines on the get/set macros or functions. Specially in parser, to get token value, yyget_text(scanner) instead of plain yytext. I think you touched this subject when you mentioned yyget_debug.

Comment: @asinix. "Outside of yylex, all accesses (and modifications, in the case of mutable variables) must be done with getter and setter functions documented in the Flex manual. " (WIth a link to the relevant page in the manual.) This answer, although already too long, is not intended to replace reading the manuals.

Comment: Hi @rici, what if I want to pass an extra user data pointer to both flex and bison? How should I implement it?

Comment: @linrongbin: With a reentrant lexer, you can add a user data pointer to the "extra data" in the scanner object. Since you have to pass that scanner object through the parser, it will be available there as well.