# yyllocp->first_line returns uninitialized value in second iteration of a reEntrant Bison parser

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I have a reEntrant parser which takes input from a string and has a structure to maintain context. 
A function is called with different input strings to be parsed. Relevant code of that function is:

```
void parseMyString(inputToBeParsed) {

 //LEXICAL COMPONENT - INITIATE LEX PROCESSING
   yyscan_t scanner;    
   YY_BUFFER_STATE  buffer;
   yylex_init_extra(&parseSupportStruct, &scanner );
   //yylex_init(&scanner);

   buffer = yy_scan_buffer(inputToBeParsed, i+2, scanner);

   if (buffer == NULL) {
       strcpy(errorStrings,"YY_BUFFER_STATE returned NULL pointer\n");
       return (-1);
   }


//BISON PART - THE ACTUAL PARSER
yyparse(scanner, &parseSupportStruct);

...

yylex_destroy(scanner);
...
}
```

My .l options are:

```
 %option noinput nounput noyywrap 8bit nodefault                                 
 %option yylineno
 %option reentrant bison-bridge bison-locations                                  
 %option extra-type="parseSupportStructType *"
```

Relevant lines from .y are:

```
  %define api.pure full
  %locations
  %param { yyscan_t scanner }
  %parse-param { parseSupportStructType* parseSupportStruct}
  %code {
    int yylex(YYSTYPE* yylvalp, YYLTYPE* yyllocp, yyscan_t scanner);
    void yyerror(YYLTYPE* yyllocp, yyscan_t unused, parseSupportStructType* parseSupportStruct,  const char* msg);
    char *yyget_text (yyscan_t);
    char *strcpy(char *, const char *);
  }
  %union {
     int numval;
     char *strval;
     double floatval; 
  }
```

**In my parser, in some rules, I try to access yyllocp->first_line.
In the first call to parseMyString(...), I get the correct value.
The second time, I get some uninitialized value. Do I need to initialize yyllocp->first_line in each call to parseMyString? How and where?**
I know I have given partial, redacted code, to explain the situation. Will be happy to provide further details.

Using valgrind I have removed memory leaks to the best of my abilites but some third-party library issues are beyond my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in flex or bison will maintain the value of `yylloc`.

Bison parsers (other than push parsers) will initialise that variable. (If you accept the default location type -- that is, you don't `#define YYLTYPE` -- `yylloc` will be initialised to `{1, 1, 1, 1}`. Otherwise, it will be zero-initialised, whatever that means for whatever type it is.) Bison also produces code which computes the location of a non-terminal based on the locations of the non-terminal's first and last children. Flex's generated code doesn't touch the location object at all.

A flex scanner does automatically maintain `yylineno` if you ask enabled this feature with

```
%option yylineno
```

Flex can usually do that more efficiently than you can, and it handles all the corner cases (`yyless`, `yymore`, `input()`, `REJECT`). So if you want to track line numbers, I strongly recommend letting flex do it.

But there is one important issue with flex's `yylineno` support. In a reentrant scanner, the line number is stored in each flex buffer, not in the scanner state object. That's almost certainly the correct place to store it, IMHO, because if you are using multiple buffers, they probably represent multiple input steams, and normally you'll want to cite the number of a line within its file. But `yy_scan_buffer` does not initialise this field. (And therefore neither do `yy_scan_string` and `yy_scan_bytes`, which are just wrappers around `yy_scan_buffer`.)

So if you are using one of the `yy_scan_*` interfaces, you should reset `yylineno` by calling `yyset_lineno` immediately after `yy_scan_*`. In your case, this would be:

```
buffer = yy_scan_buffer(inputToBeParsed, i+2, scanner);
yyset_lineno(1, scanner);
```

Once you've got `yylineno`, it's easy to maintain the `yylloc` object. Flex has a hook which lets you inject code just before any the action for a pattern is executed (even if the action is empty) and this hook can be used to automatically maintain `yylloc`. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48879103/1566221), I provide a simple example of this technique (which depends on `yylineno` being maintained by the flex-generated scanner):

```
#define YY_USER_ACTION                                             \
  yylloc->first_line = yylloc->last_line;                          \
  yylloc->first_column = yylloc->last_column;                      \
  if (yylloc->last_line == yylineno)                               \
    yylloc->last_column += yyleng;                                 \
  else {                                                           \
    yylloc->last_line = yylineno;                                  \
    yylloc->last_column = yytext + yyleng - strrchr(yytext, '\n'); \
  }
```

As the notes in that answer indicate, the above is not fully general, but it will work in many circumstances:

> This `YY_USER_ACTION` macro should work for any scanner which does not use `yyless()`, `yymore()`, `input()` or `REJECT`. Correctly coping with these features is not too difficult but it seemed out of scope here.

You cannot handle `yyless()`, `yymore()` or `REJECT` before the action (since before the action it's not possible to know if they will be executed), so a more robust location-tracker in an application which used those features would have to include code to fix `yylloc()`:

- For `yyless()`, the above code for setting `last_line` and `last_column` can be re-executed after the `yyless()` call, since the flex scanner will fix `yyleng` and `yylineno`.
- For `REJECT`, it is not possible to insert code after `REJECT`. The only way to handle it is to keep a backup of `yylloc` and restore it immediately before the `REJECT` macro. (I strongly advise against using `REJECT`. It's extremely inefficient and can almost always be replaced with the combination of a call to `yyless()` and a start condition.)
- For `yymore()`, `yylloc` is still correct, but the *next* action must not overwrite the token start position. Getting that right would probably require maintaining a flag to indicate whether or not `yymore()` had been called.
- For `input()`, if you want the characters read to be considered part of the current token, you could advance the end location in `yylloc` after the call to `input()` (which requires distinguishing between `input()` returning a newline, an end-of-file indicator, or a regular character). Alternatively, if you want the characters read with `input()` to not be considered part of any token, you would need to abandon the idea of using the end position of the previous token as the start position of the current token, which would require keeping a separation position value to be used as the start position of the next token.

Comment: Most of my bison/flex code is based upon your answers! I ended up maintaining line count myself as my problem is that yylineno starts with some uninitialized value, the second time I call the function. The first iteration works just fine.

Comment: @asinix: I integrated my previous comment into the answer, and added more details. Let me know if it still makes sense to you. I think I didn't understand your issue at first because you asked about `yylloc`, not `yylineno`, but when you mentioned `yylineno` being uninitialised, I remembered the problem with `yy_scan_buffer` not initialising it. So sorry for not having been more on the ball in the first place. (I don't usually have this problem because I almost always use push parsers, which require a different way of handling location objects.)

Comment: I tried but I get the error "yyset_lineno called with no buffer". I must admit that I have my parser working because I took a lot of your suggestions blindly and they just work!! I have a functional, reEntrant, buffer-based parser working just fine with all your suggestions. Otherwise, writing a parser in bison and flex is a whole lot of work!

Comment: @asinix: I'll double-check when I get home. `yy_scan_buffer` should have installed a buffer, unless of course it returned NULL.

Comment: @asinix: so the error message was actually correct :-) Glad you got it working.